# good reference on brieskorn manifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to learn something on the Brieskorn manifold (interested in the topological property)

Can the Mathoverflow Experts give me some good refencece (in English)?

By the way,is there an English translation of the following paper by Brieskorn:

### Beispiele zur Differentialtopologie von Singularitäten

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add Milnor's book   ***"Singular points of complex hypersufaces"***  Ann of Math Studies, No. 61, Princeton University Press,  1968.

Answer (score 5):

You may try the following paper by John Milnor: *[On the 3-dimensional Brieskorn manifolds M(p,q,r)](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnbries.pdf)*, in: Knots, groups, and 3-manifolds, pp. 175–225. Ann. of Math. Studies, No. 84, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, N.J., 1975.